# What do I need to consider to choose Ethereum Client?

Tags: go-ethereum, infura, clients, alchemy, openethereum

I'm trying to create a node and realized there are several open sources for Ethereum client such as Geth, OpenEthereum, Erigon and Nethremind.

I would like to know...

1. Which one is the most used and why?
2. Which one do Node providers(Alchemy, Infura, ...) use?

Comment: It depends on the purpose of the node. I'd recommend edit your question a bit and add some more background why are you doing this and what is your goal. https://xyproblem.info/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi dev advocate at [Chainstack](https://chainstack.com/) here!

- **Answer to question 1)**

  Geth is definitely the most used for now. There are a few reasons why. Still, the main one is that Go Ethereum (Geth) is the official Go land implementation for running the Ethereum client, which resulted in a significant adoption from the beginning.

  Also, its usage is well known and has a big community that provides good support when someone encounters a problem, or the software needs improvements.

  Erigon is catching up. As the networks grow, we will need more efficient use of hardware resources. Erigon saves a lot of hard drive space compared to Geth and allows to sync up new nodes in significantly less time.

You can check some stats on [ethernodes](https://www.ethernodes.org/) and on this article about [full and archive nodes](https://chainstack.com/evm-nodes-a-dive-into-the-full-vs-archive-mode/).

- **Answer to question 2)**

  Node providers run clients based on the network and often give you a choice.

  For example, Chainstack runs Geth for Ethereum by default, but you can also choose to deploy an ETH node using Erigon.

  In addition, other EVM-based chains have their own client, usually, a fork of Geth, such as [Avalanche Go](https://github.com/ava-labs/avalanchego) for the Avalanche network or [Go Opera](https://github.com/Fantom-foundation/go-opera) for Fantom, etc.

**To recap:**

Geth is probably the best for support and documentation if you want to run your own node, making it easier to run with less experience.

Erigon would be best if you are concerned about hardware resources or want to explore the "new frontier" of clients. I think having experience running Erigon would be best as we'll inevitably need to go in that direction.

Answer (score 0):

Geth is by far the most popular in Ethereum Proof of Work: https://etherscan.io/nodetracker . As for why... My best guess is because it's the oldest existing client. For some time there wasn't even much competition and Geth was almost the only working client.

I don't know what node providers use. Most likely they run multiple - one of them as primary, and others as fail-safes in case something goes wrong with the main client.

Do note that Ethereum will switch to Proof of Stake in a few weeks and client diversity looks very different on that side: https://clientdiversity.org/ . If you're considering building a client of your own, I strongly recommend to do it on the PoS side - the old clients will no longer work after the Merge.